# Select a specific node meeting several conditions

Tags: xml, xslt

My problem is the following: I try to apply a specific `template` to nodes meeting several conditions. My XML looks like:

```
<Root>
  <A>
    <id>1</id>
    <B>
      <C>
        <name>C_name1</name>
        <D>
          <E>label1</E>
          <E>label2</E>
        </D>
      </C>
      <C>
        <name>C_name2</name>
        <D>
          <E>label1</E>
          <E>label3</E>
        </D>
      </C>
    </B>
  </A>
  <A>
    ...
  </A>
</Root>
```

I want to select all `A` nodes such that `A[B/C/name = 'specific_name']` AND if that node exists, I also want A such this node meets `` D/E = `specific_label' ``. Therefore I want something like `A[B/C[name = 'specific_name']/D/E = 'specific_label']` but this syntax does not work ...

What is the correct syntax to fulfill my requirements and apply my template on the right nodes ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the answer you found, one can use the following XPath expression:

```
A[B/C[name='specific_name' and D/E='specific_label']]
```

**This  is the only correct way of connecting multiple conditions, if some of them contain the `position()` function**, which is contextually - dependent and typically has different values when included in different predicates.

Comment: ah! I was about to suggest samething :) +1.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the right syntax appears to be:

```
<xsl:template match="Root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="A[B/C[name='specific_name'][D/E='specific_label']]" />
</xsl:template>
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Does it mean you've found answer to your question? If so, please mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: I came up with the same solution. Nice that nested brackets are allowed in XSLT :-)

Comment: Yes I found the answer but I cannot accept my own answer before 2 days! I agree with you Maestro: I just didn't think about them at first :)

Comment: You can also use: `A[B/C[name='specific_name' and D/E='specific_label']] `. This  is the only correct way of connecting multiple conditions, if some of them contain the `position()` function, which is contextually - dependent.